# Put method is not working 403 forbidden response

Tags: javascript, java, angular, request, multipart

When I send a put request to a user in my spring boot backend, I got a 403 forbidden response. But when I send the same request through postman it gets updates. Can anyone help me to correct my code? I'll put all the relevant code segments below. (front - angular-cli 12, back - spring boot)

**front end requesting method**

```
    updateUser(userId: string, profilePic: string, shortDes: string, username: string, email: string, phoneNumber: string): Observable<any> {
    const body: FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('id', userId);
    body.append('username', username);
    body.append('email', email);
    body.append('shortDes', shortDes);
    body.append('profilePic', profilePic);
    body.append('phoneNum', phoneNumber);
    console.log(userId,username,)
    return this.http.put<HttpResponse<any>>(environment.baseUrl + `/api/v1/users/` + userId, body,{
      observe: 'response'
    });
  }
```

**backend receiving method**

```
@PutMapping(
            value = "/{id}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser( @ModelAttribute UserBody body, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        if (body.getId() != id) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Mismatch userId !!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else if (true) {
            // TODO: 5/26/2022   handle the multi part file size from this stage before save it
        }
        try {
            String filePath = null;
            if (body.getProfilePic() != null) {
                filePath = fileService.saveUserProfilePicture(body.getProfilePic());
                UserDTO user = bo.getUser(id);
                fileService.deleteFile(user.getProfilePicture());
            }
            UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
            dto.setId(body.getId());
            dto.setUsername(body.getUsername());
            dto.setEmail(body.getEmail());
            dto.setShortDescription(body.getShortDes());
            dto.setProfilePicture(filePath);
            dto.setContactNum(body.getPhoneNum());
            bo.updateUserNormalDetails(dto);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(dto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("No user is found !!", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**postman request**
[image]

The error I get from the spring-boot backend when I send a put request from the front-end

2022-07-04 10:44:40.619  WARN 3068 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.springframework.validation.DataBinder  : Skipping URI variable 'id' because request contains bind value with same name.

**HTTP request via browser** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't get an error, you get a warning. The 403 indicates you aren't sending the proper authentication information.

Comment: @M.Deinum did you mean the authoriation part? I set all requirements using an angular intercepter. (you can see, I've uploaded the image. please see the last image)

Comment: Your screenshots show 201 and 400, not 403.

Comment: @CherryDT yes but when I double click the 400 response in network tab I get

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu Jul 07 12:57:23 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)